# Running stored procedure in SQL developer calling another procedure ends connection

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm running into a strange issue with SQL developer. I have written a procedure that calls another procedure, located in a different schema.

Running the procedure without calling the other-schema-procedure works fine.
Running just the procedure in the other schema works fine.

Whenever I execute the stored procedure in the other schema from the original procedure, it ends successfully, but afterwards I need to reconnect to the database to be able to do something. It seems the connection gets lost by calling the procedure in a different schema.

Has anyone seen similar issues or does anyone have an idea how I can chase the root cause of this (Oracle or SQL developer)?

This is Oracle 12C (12.2) and SQL developer 3.0.04

Comment: Check for trace files or dba_errors if you could to find what went wrong.

Comment: check the alert log as well - i imagine the db or the driver are having an issue. also, you're using a very old jdbc driver in v3 of SQLDev upgrade to version 17.3.1 and you'll have a 12.2 jdbc driver connecting to a 12.2 oracle database = much better scenario